# How do I create a websocket client in C# Asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, websocket, client

Good morning,
how can I connect to Websocket in C# Asp.net MVC while keeping the connection active?

i'm looking on the net but i only find to create servers and not clients

Answer (score 0):

There is tutorial for .net 5 -> https://sahansera.dev/understanding-websockets-with-aspnetcore-5/

And for .net core 3.1 everything similar, but insted of using Controller you need to use midleware

```
public class WebSocketMiddleware
{
    ...

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
            if (!context.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 400;
                return;
            }

            WebSocket socket = await context.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();

            ...
    }
}
```

Or ofcorse you can use SignalR https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-5.0

But most information u can find in official docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 0):

Oh, sorry, u are looking for clients ...

You can make a service class to process your WebSocketClient and with async connect/disconnect methods.
Than just call this methods inside some IHostedService.